# How do you change a string to a list without separating all the characters?

Tags: python, string, python-chess

I'm using the python-chess module to write a chess engine. Here's the code that I'm struggling with, for context:

```
def move_search():
    move_evals = []
    legal_moves = list(board.legal_moves)
    for move in range (len(legal_moves)):
        board.push(legal_moves[move - 1])
        board_eval()
        '''The above function is just an irrelevant 
        snippet that gets the advantage score. 
        I think it's very unlikely that's causing the problem.'''

        move_evals.append(score)
        board.pop()
    string_moves = list(str(legal_moves)) 
    print(str(legal_moves))   
    move_evals, string_moves = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(move_evals, string_moves))))
    print(move_evals)     
    print(string_moves)
```

I had to add the `string_moves` because just using the `legal_moves` list returned this error:

```
line 123, in move_search
move_evals, legal_moves = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(move_evals, legal_moves))))
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Move' and 'Move'
```

However, `string_moves` returns an overly long list with each character in the list `legal_moves` as one element of the list. How do I explicitly tell Python that I want it to be a list with the original elements, but just as a `'string'` instance?

Expected vs. Actual Output (as kindly requested by Mark Tolonen:)
Expected:

```
[Move.from_uci('g1h3'), Move.from_uci('g1f3'), 
Move.from_uci('b1c3'), Move.from_uci('b1a3'), 
Move.from_uci('h2h3'), Move.from_uci('g2g3'), 
Move.from_uci('f2f3'), Move.from_uci('e2e3'), 
Move.from_uci('d2d3'), Move.from_uci('c2c3'), 
Move.from_uci('b2b3'), Move.from_uci('a2a3'), 
Move.from_uci('h2h4'), Move.from_uci('g2g4'), 
Move.from_uci('f2f4'), Move.from_uci('e2e4'), 
Move.from_uci('d2d4'), Move.from_uci('c2c4'), 
Move.from_uci('b2b4'), Move.from_uci('a2a4')]
```

Actual:

```
['[', 'M', 'o', 'v', 'e', '.', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', 
'_', 'u', 'c', 'i', '(', "'", 'g', '1', 'h', '3', 
"'", ')', ',', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'v', 'e', '.', 'f', 
'r', 'o', 'm', '_', 'u', 'c', 'i', '(', "'", 'g', 
'1', 'f', '3', "'", ')', ',', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'v', 
'e', '.', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', '_', 'u', 'c', 'i', 
'(', "'", 'b', '1', 'c', '3', "'", ')', ',', ' ', 
'M', 'o', 'v', 'e', '.', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', '_', 
'u', 'c', 'i', '(', "'", 'b', '1', 'a', '3', "'", 
')', ',', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'v', 'e', '.', 'f', 'r', 
'o', 'm', '_', 'u', 'c', 'i', '(', "'", 'h', '2', 
'h', '3', "'", ')', ',', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'v', 'e', 
'.', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', '_', 'u', 'c', 'i', '(', 
"'", 'g', '2', 'g', '3', "'", ')', ',', ' ', 'M', 
'o', 'v', 'e', '.', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', '_', 'u', 
'c', 'i', '(', "'", 'f', '2', 'f', '3', "'", ')', 
',', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'v', 'e', '.', 'f', 'r', 'o', 
'm', '_', 'u', 'c', 'i', '(', "'", 'e', '2', 'e', 
'3', "'", ')', ',', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'v', 'e', '.', 
'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', '_', 'u', 'c', 'i', '(', "'", 
'd', '2', 'd', '3', "'", ')', ',', ' ', 'M', 'o', 
'v', 'e', '.', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', '_', 'u', 'c', 
'i', '(', "'", 'c', '2', 'c', '3', "'", ')', ',', ' 
', 'M', 'o', 'v', 'e', '.', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', 
'_', 'u', 'c', 'i', '(', "'", 'b', '2', 'b', '3', 
"'", ')', ',', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'v', 'e', '.', 'f', 
'r', 'o', 'm', '_', 'u', 'c', 'i', '(', "'", 'a', 
'2', 'a', '3', "'", ')', ',', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'v', 
'e', '.', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', '_', 'u', 'c', 'i', 
'(', "'", 'h', '2', 'h', '4', "'", ')', ',', ' ', 
'M', 'o', 'v', 'e', '.', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', '_', 
'u', 'c', 'i', '(', "'", 'g', '2', 'g', '4', "'", 
')', ',', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'v', 'e', '.', 'f', 'r', 
'o', 'm', '_', 'u', 'c', 'i', '(', "'", 'f', '2', 
'f', '4', "'", ')', ',', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'v', 'e', 
'.', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', '_', 'u', 'c', 'i', '(', 
"'", 'e', '2', 'e', '4', "'", ')', ',', ' ', 'M', 
'o', 'v', 'e', '.', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', '_', 'u', 
'c', 'i', '(', "'", 'd', '2', 'd', '4', "'", ')', 
',', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'v', 'e', '.', 'f', 'r', 'o', 
'm', '_', 'u', 'c', 'i', '(', "'", 'c', '2', 'c', 
'4', "'", ')', ',', ' ', 'M', 'o', 'v', 'e', '.', 
'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', '_', 'u', 'c', 'i', '(', "'", 
'b', '2', 'b', '4', "'", ')', ',', ' ', 'M', 'o', 
'v', 'e', '.', 'f', 'r', 'o', 'm', '_', 'u', 'c', 
'i', '(', "'", 'a', '2', 'a', '4', "'", ')', ']']
```

Comment: Make a [mcve]. Show an example of actual vs. desired output.

Comment: If you just want the string, then you need to read the documentation of the chess module you're using.  The `Move` object almost certainly has a method to return that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating that string `str(legal_moves)` at all is a mistake. Instead fix your sorting error by using an appropriate key:

```
move_evals, legal_moves = (
    list(t)
    for t in zip(*sorted(
        zip(move_evals, legal_moves),
        key=lambda t: t[0]
    ))
)
```

That sorts the `(eval, move)` pairs by the evals alone. It doesn't try to compare the moves themselves.

Alternatively, if you do want the raw moves themselves to influence the order in case of equal evals, do make `Move` objects comparable (by giving them at least a `__lt__` method). Or include them in the key, for example `key=lambda t: (t[0], t[1].as_string)` (or however the `Move` object makes its string accessible).

Answer (score -3):

I will suggest you to first `initialise the list with just an empty string` in it.

For example,

```
l = [""]
l.append("hello")
print(l)
```

The above code will print `["", "hello"]`